# How do I return a view from a spring controller using an ajax request?

Tags: java, ajax, spring

I make an ajax request using jquery, this calls the following spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dialogController", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String dialogController(Model model, @RequestBody MyClass myclass) {
  myClass.setTitle("SUCCESS");       
  model.addAttribute("myClass",myClass);
  return "dialogContent";  //this resolves to dialogContent.jsp
}
```

However I receive the following error :

```
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: 
Request method 'POST' not supported
```

And if required here is the ajax call I am making using jQuery:

```
   jq.postJSON("/dialogController", myClass, function(data) {
      myDialog.html(data);
      myDialog.dialog('open'); 
      //dialog settings previously assigned, 
      //but the success callback function is not reached anyway
    });
```

*EDIT*
I get same error if I use :

```
jq.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/dialogController",
  data:myClass,
  success:  function(data) {            
         previewDialog.html(data);
         previewDialog.dialog('open');
  });
```

Comment: Does it work fine if you use a rest client to post the JSON data? also is the } in dialogController a mistake? Also are you using a javascript library? If so which one?

Comment: @Ali Yes was a spelling mistake.  Not tried a rest client, will it make a difference as the error occurs on the spring controller ?  Same error if I do similar request but remove the json/myclass parameter.

Comment: Have you tried adding Accept="text/html, application/json" to the @RequestMapping annotation? The reason I'm recommending the RestClient is because in that you can see what the passed "accept" value was and you can try to change it to see if the error still occurs.

Comment: could you try a regular $.post(..) - postJSON is a plugin and might be problematic

Comment: @Bozho updated using jquery ajax call

Comment: try removing request method attribute from @RequestMApping

Comment: @Bozho if I change to get (and remove the posting of data) it works, somewhat - the ajax success callback function is executed, however the jsp is not displayed - its blank. I am about to try adding ResponseBody annotation to my return string (in controller).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the viewers at home ... I found that the problem was due to the method signature defined in controller not matching the ajax call. I removed the `Model model` parameter from controller method.  I also then realized I had to also return a new model and view; here is the working code:

```
var myJSON  = {"title":"help"}; 
myJSON = JSON.stringify(myJSON);

<c:url var="postAndView" value="/PostJSONMAV" />
...
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "${postAndView}",
    data:myJSON,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success:  function(data) {          
        previewDialog.html(data);
        previewDialog.dialog('open');
    }
});
```

I changed to the ajax call but `jQuery.postJSON()` will probably work aswell. And shown below is the new controller code, which corrrectly adds a new object to model and returns jsp page, which is opened up in a dialog:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/PostJSONMAV", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public  ModelAndView postJSON(@RequestBody MyClass myClass) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    myClass.setTitle("SUCCESS");
    mav.setViewName("dialogContent");
    mav.addObject("myClass", myClass);
    return mav;     
}
```