# How to Retrieve a spring controller's object in AJAX?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

My AJAX call:

```
var url = "UsersGroupReader.html?selectedCompanyName=" + selectedCompanyName + "&test="+Math.random();
req.onreadystatechange = processAccessGroupRequest;
req.open("GET", url, true); 
req.send(null);

function processAccessGroupRequest() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        alert("req.status : " + req.status)
    if (req.status == 200) {
            var message = req.responseXML
            alert("message " + message);
            if (message == "No Database Connection") {
                alert("Please check the database connection");
            } else if (message == "DataDeleted") {
                //alert("Data has been deleted from Database. Please LOGOUT and try again");
                alert("Access Denied");
            } else {
                //setAccessGroups(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "Jsp/UsersGroupReader.html", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Vector<String> readUsersGroup(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpSession httpSession) {
        .....
        .....
        return Vector;
```

The `req.responseXML` is `null`

The returned `vector` object is to be read in the `javascript` but I don't know how to do?
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7065292/106261

Comment: @NimChimpsky I already checked it and it was very useful. But you didn't mention the way in which you used the `mav` object. That being my doubt.

Comment: what is the response content type you are looking for json/xml

Comment: @ArunPJohny I want to receive a vector object from the controller. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Freakuser in my other example I just open a dialog with the model view as the html, its in the answer I gave. Also, I recmommned jQuery takes away some of the boilerplate ajax stuff.

Comment: @NimChimpsky oh I see, so you have used the object inside the dialog, haven't you? Is there any idea how to use the object in the same `jsp`?

Comment: @Freakyuser yeah in my example its the javascript data variable/object ... its not in the dialog. Its used by a javascript function in my jsp to polute a div, that div is used by jquery ui to open a dialog box. You can do pretty much whatever you want with it...

Comment: @NimChimpsky No Nim, an object from a controller is retrieved here in my example. I don't know how to process that.

Comment: @Freakyuser No ? Which part of what I said do you disagree with ?

Comment: in yr question it looks like the variable message is used to hold th response from server, which looks itself like being an xml object ... again, you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: You don't get " an object " back from the request, you get text. That text should be either JSON or XML, making it easier to evaluate on the JS side. Hopefully you understand that JavaScript running on the client doesn't know anything about Java or its data types.

Comment: I would suggest you to use json as the data format and use json2 library in the client side and spring mvc with jackson in the server side.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have used the jackson in the server side. What is with the json2 in the client side? I didn't get that. Still I am unable to get an object in the js function.

Comment: It is a library which will allow you to parse/stringify json object in the client side in browsers like IE. modern libraries implements `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` nativly. Any way what is the return value you want to use? is it an array/list or an object like map? You can use the `@ResponseBody` annotation in your controller and return the object from the handler method instead of `ModelAndView`.

Comment: @ArunPJohny The return value is a `vector object`. I have updated the controller.

Comment: Do you have jackson library in your classpath

Comment: I have `jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar` `jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.4.jar` in my classpath.

Comment: You need to add the header req.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

Comment: I would suggest you to use jackson 2 if you are using spring 3.1 or above

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the return type of your controller method which is handling this ajax request. The return type should be the class which type of object you want in your jsp. eg. `List<String>` or any other custom class you have.

And you must also declare annotation `@ResponseBody` on your controller function handling this request. And you will also need JSON library like `jackson-core-asl` and `jackson-core-mapper` version 1.5. That will convert your return type class object in a JSON object and you will get that in response. And your `@RequestMapping` annotation should declare `produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`.

syntax for produces attribute.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/xxx/yyy", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I have changed the return type to `vector<string>` as said. And also I have given `@ResponseBody`. Thank you. But I am unable to use the `produces` attribute in `@RequestMapping`. Are you sure about it? I am getting this error *attribute produces is undefined for the annotation type RequestMapping*

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure about the produces attribute in @RequestMapping annotation. Its syntax I've edited in the answer. Please have a look at it.

Comment: The attribute `produces` is undefined for the annotation type `RequestMapping`. This is the error I am getting. I don't know if I am missing some jar. I have `jackson-core-asl` and `jackson-core-mapper` in the build path

Comment: What is the spring version you are using? I searched on net and found that it is available after spring 3.1.0.RELEASE version.

Comment: The jar files I have are of 3.0.3 release. Can't I do the task with these jars

Comment: Yeah. You need to change the spring version to 3.1.0.RELEASE. Or you can try using `response.setContentType("application/json");`

Comment: I tried with all these jars `spring-web` 3.1.0, 3.1.1 & 3.1.2. The `produces` attribute is recognised but all these jars generate this error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.getEnvironment()`. Don't know what to do for this. This didn't occur for `3.0.3`.

Comment: You need to make sure the schemas in xml file are changed as per the new version. Also make sure the jars are in your classpath and lib folder. Try to find this class and method in jar.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have got it. Its working now. I already had checked for the method in the `3.0.3` version and the `3.1.1`. It is missing in the `3.1.1` but present in the `3.0.3`. Anyway now that I have all new jars `jackson-core-asl-1.9.7` `jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.4` `all spring jars version 3.1.1`, it should have come from some other jar. The only thing is, I have got struck with the retrieval of the `vector` object in the `javascript`.

Comment: I am not sure about vector, but I have used @ResponseBody with List<> and its working fine. Can you check with List<>.

Comment: Let us presume that the `vector` is sent to the client side somehow. My doubt is how to retrieve it in the client side.

Comment: On the client side you will get the JSON string in the response. Which is itself an array. Now you just need to iterate it in a for loop and access each index like arr[i] and its respective property in order arr[i][0].