# invoke @Postmapping using ajax is not working

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-4

Controller with new implementation

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/something.do")
public class ExampleController {

        @GetMapping
        public ModelAndView getSomething(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {
            //do something
        }

        @PostMapping(params = { "param1=user1", "process=update" })
        public ModelAndView updateuser1(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("userData") UserData data) {
            // do something
        }

        @PostMapping(params = { "param1=user2", "process=update" })
        public ModelAndView updateuser1(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("userData") UserData data) {
            // do something
        }

    }
```

Ajax call

```js
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url : "something.do?&param1=user1&process=update",
  success : function(data) {
    // do something
   });
  },
  error : function() {
   // do something
  },
  data : $("#form").serialize(),
  timeout : 50000
 });
```

When i try to invoke one of the post method it is giving me POST method not supported exception
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported

But with my old implementation it is working fine.

old implementation:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/something.do")
public class ExampleController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET
    public ModelAndView getSomething(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {
        //do something
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "param1=user1", "process=update" })
    public ModelAndView updateuser1(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("userData") UserData data) {
        // do something
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "param1=user2", "process=update" })
    public ModelAndView updateuser1(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("userData") UserData data) {
        // do something
    }

}
```

Can someone please tell me if i am using @PostMapping in a right way? Ajax call is failing when it invokes PostMapping.

Comment: Why are returning `ModelView` ?

Comment: I have changed request handler methods to return view. But i still have issue invoking PostMapping with ajax call.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028507/how-do-i-return-a-view-from-a-spring-controller-using-an-ajax-request