# Why does my spring boot controller not display a new view after ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Similar questions have already been asked for example this one [How do I return a view from a spring controller using an ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028507/how-do-i-return-a-view-from-a-spring-controller-using-an-ajax-request) 
however the answers do not give me any solution to my problem. 
I also want to add that i am new to frontend development.

My problem is that i am calling a controller method with an ajax-script and after the call i want the user to be redirected to another view from the controller. However the returned view does not display in the browser, instead the browser remain in the view from which the script is triggered.

Although it seems that the return statement in the controller works in some way because in the browsers console i can see the html that is supposed to be displayed in the browsers window.

Another odd thing is that when i call other controllers in my project with parameters via thymeleaf the returned views are displayed as they are supposed to.

How can i direct the view "recipesOverviewPage" from the controller to be displayed in the browser instead of being displayed as html-tags in the console.

My script:

```
 const sendArray = function() {
            var ingredientNames = [];

            $('#insertedFoodsList li').each(function(index) {
                ingredientNames.push($(this).text());
            });

            ingredientNames = JSON.stringify({
                'ingredientNames': ingredientNames
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: "/foo",
                type: 'POST',
                data: ingredientNames,
                dataType: "html",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                mimeType: 'application/json',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                return false;
                }
            });
        };
```

The button that triggers the event:

```
<div class="btn" value="Submit" onclick="sendArray();" style="margin-left: 9em">Generate recipe</div>
```

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getSearchedRecipesFromIngredientInputField(@RequestBody RecipeSearchObject recipeSearchObject, Model model) {
model.addAttribute("recipeList",recipeService.getRecipesByIngredientList(recipeSearchObject.getIngredientNames()));
        return "recipesOverviewPage";
    }
```

Comment: Did yo ucheck your console log ?

Comment: And what do you think should happen that doesn't happen.

Comment: @Frank Pentangeli In my console is the html-document from the view that i want to display to the user. But i want it to be displayed as a webpage.

Comment: M. Deinum i want the view "recipesOverviewPage" to be displayed in the browser after the ajax-script is called.